Audio Output Problems on Infinix X2 Slim Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and Newer Versions
Encountering issues with audio output on my Infinix X2 Slim laptop after installing Ubuntu 20.04 or latest versions. how to troubleshoot and resolve these problems. While headphones function correctly, the laptop's built-in speakers remain silent despite audio activity being detected. Discover effective methods to diagnose and rectify these audio output challenges.
please resolve this .
